# LUA IDE that supports 'jump to definition' cross file

Tags: lua, ide

I am looking for a nice IDE for LUA, that supports 'jump to definition', even if that definition is in another file (in the same project).

I am mostly using Intellij, but all plugins dont seem to support this.

For example:

```
-- classtest.lua

Account = {}
Account.__index = Account

function Account:create(balance)
    local acnt = {}             -- our new object
    setmetatable(acnt,Account)  -- make Account handle lookup
    acnt.balance = balance      -- initialize our object
    return acnt
end

function Account:withdraw(amount)
    self.balance = self.balance - amount
end
```

Now in another file i do:

```
require("classtest");

local acc = Account:create(1000)
acc:withdraw(100);
```

I want to be able to jump to the `withdraw` function.
It would greatly help me, cause right now, refactoring and code navigation is very tedious.

Comment: Please understand that Lua doesn't "require" that a file loaded and executed by `require` does anything at all. In some schemes, it would return a table that would be captured in a local variable. In your scheme, it sets a global variable to a table. It is notable that the variable name doesn't even match the file name. You are expecting an IDE to figure this out (probably without even running the code.) Of course, It's a great feature that would help in coding but, fuzzy matching is likely the best you are going to find.

Comment: One possiblity (that could be a lot of work) is an editor that supports ctags. The [ltags](https://github.com/stevedonovan/ltags) Lua scanner might help with that.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/), as it provides fuzzy symbol matching, so you can select `withdraw` and go to `Search | Navigate | Go to Symbol` (`Ctrl/Cmd-B`) to show the list of symbols matching across the entire project. In most cases the first match will be what you'd expect, so you can simply press Enter to jump there. The fuzzy search also shows you the preview of the symbol definition.

Comment: Thank you, i will check it out! Do you have any other suggestions, or is zeroBrane the only one that supports this?

Comment: This is the one I'm the most familiar with, as I've been developing it.